# Persistent URL query string throughout the entire site?

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-analytics, global-variables, query-string

This is one of those situations where I feel like there is a simple answer right in front of me...hopefully you guys/gals can show me the light.

**PROBLEM :**

I have a client that wants to maintain a query string across all pages on their site, only if they arrived at the site via a link that contains the query string.

This query string would also need to be passed with any external link from the site.

**INFORMATION :**

An example of the query string :

`?utm_medium=<ad_placement>&utm_source=<ad_source>`

(Obviously this is for tracking conversions from ads)

We're currently tracking all this stuff via Google Analytics (so, yes, I know that's an alternative), this is for an extra layer of reporting.

I did not code their site, which brings it's own set of issues (example: I'm not even sure they use a common header among all pages) - so I'm hoping there is a KISS answer out there for this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

So - the answer here was this :

1. Use JS to grab the query string
2. Validate the query string
3. Add to a cookie
4. Append the cookie'd query string to every href in the DOM

Like I said...I knew there was a simple example staring me in the face haha!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to persist this exact query string on each page, why not set the linked pages to insert the string into a session variable.  Then on each page link check to see if the session variable exists and add it to the query string when redirecting.

Comment: Great suggestion @Seano666 - this is probably what I'll end up doing. I was hoping for a higher level solution that would not involve modifying (potentially) dozens or even hundreds of files/links (...part of the baggage that comes along with working on another programmer's site sometimes I guess...). I wonder if there is an .htaccess solution...hmmmmmm

Comment: If every link on every page is made the same, say an <a> tag or a <div> with a certain class, you could include a master .js file that on page load seeks them out with a jquery selector and adds on to the href.  Something like that, just an idea.

Comment: That's pretty much the route I decided on. Basically use JS to grab the query string, check it for a match against the required persistent vars, store in a cookie, then append to all hrefs in the DOM. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This question is old and obviously must have been solved by now by @aepearson.
Adding another answer from current day perspective.

> Now, one can also easily use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) also to save navigation data into a key. Pick it up whenever required, and add to url.

Example from Mozilla

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```