# How to detect parameters globally and keep the state after navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find the way to keep the parameters in the url upon navigation if they are entered once, ie: `?aff=john`

So for example, user comes to `website.com/?aff=john` and navigates to `about-us` I need to make that url parameters are kept, so the full website name is: `website.com/about-us/?aff=john`

This is what I've tried so far, but it is not working.. it keeps adding the url parameters (`window.location.search`)

```
var params = false
var baseUrl = ''
var currUrl = window.location.href

if (window.location.search != '') {
  params = true
}

if (params) {
  baseUrl = currUrl + window.location.search
  window.location.href = baseUrl
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT: already tried proposed.. not working.

Comment: This sounds like a real pain to maintain. Why not use a session variable, or cookie to store the value when set by the first page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persistent URL query string throughout the entire site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214497/persistent-url-query-string-throughout-the-entire-site)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How can I interpolate it then in the `location.href`?

Comment: You can use a javascript to grab the query string, put it into a cookie then add the cookie string to every href of your document.

Comment: @DanieleFois Can you please post the working solution?

Comment: first try by yourself... when you get stuck you'll surely find somebody who will help you

Comment: I didi try. So you only copied answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214497/persistent-url-query-string-throughout-the-entire-site but the truth is you don't know as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to save navigation data into a key. Pick it up whenever required. Now-a-days, [all browsers support it except Opera mini](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=sessionstorage).

Hopefully, your software does not have browser constraints and your application does not have to work on outdated browsers.

As copied from mozilla site,  code to use sessionstorage would be like :

```
    // Save data to sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value'); 

    // Get saved data from sessionStorage 
     var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key'); 

    // Remove a key from sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.removeItem('key'); 

    // Remove all data from sessionStorage 
     sessionStorage.clear();
```

This way, you won't need to append it on every page. For the domain url and in current browser session, you can get it from sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the query string using window.location.search and then you can add link handler in using jQuery like below:

```
var glString = window.location.search;
$('a').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + glString;
});
```

or if you prefer javascript

```
var glString = window.location.search;
var links = document.getElementByTagName('a');
links.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + glString;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporary save the previous url using **sessionStorage**.

`sessionStorage.setItem('parameter', 'dataString');
    sessionStorage.getItem("parameter");`